# python logging: how to get compressed .gz log file using TimedRotatingFileHandler

Tags: python

I want to have my log file daily based rotate and compress the log file to `.gz` format.

```
loghandler = TimedRotatingFileHandler(logging_file, when='midnight')
logformatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s [%(levelname)s] %(message)s')
loghandler.setFormatter(logformatter)
LOGGER = logging.getLogger()
LOGGER.setLevel(logging.INFO)
LOGGER.addHandler(loghandler)
```

By using this, the log is only daily based rotating. How can I get a compressed file?

Comment: Check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7010572/1338158)

Comment: @kroolik Actually i just tried this method, but it doesn't work.

Comment: @kroolik The `.gz` file contains nothing. Is it because the rotated log file has time suffix. In `doRollover`, he uses `baseFilename` which doesn't have the time suffix?

Comment: Check this answer [Python, want logging with log rotation and compression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8467978/python-want-logging-with-log-rotation-and-compression)